# How to solve for $x$ : $ae^{bx}+x = c$

Tags: lambert-w

How to solve for $x$ :  $ae^{bx}+x = c$

I've tried to solve it with the Lambert W function, but, in all of the methods I tried, I had $x$  as the Lambert W function parameter. Can I solve it without graphs? Thank you for your help.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790499/how-does-one-solve-for-x-in-the-equality-ax-bx-c) might prove useful to solve the related 

$$(e^b)^x - \left( - \frac 1 a \right) x = \frac c a$$

which after multiplication by $a$ should give you your equation.

Comment: WolframAlpha shows a solution [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+ae%5E%7Bbx%7D%2Bx+%3D+c+for+x) as

$$x = c - \frac{W_n(a b e^{b c})}{b}\quad 
\text{for } b\ne0 \land a b\ne0 \land n \in\mathbb{ Z}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ae^{bx}+x=c$$

$$ae^{bx}=c-x$$

$$ae^{bc-b(c-x)}=c-x$$

$$abe^{bc}=b(c-x)e^{b(c-x)}$$

$$b(c-x)=W(abe^{bc}).$$

$$x=c-\frac1bW(abe^{bc}).$$

(By hand.)