# Solve equation $a\exp({k_{1}x}) - b\exp({k_{2}x}) + c = 0$

Tags: exponential-function, elementary-functions

I am looking for the solution of an equation just like

$$ae^{k_{1}x} - be^{k_{2}x} + c = 0$$

where $a$, $b$, $k_{1}$, $k_{2}$ are known real constants, $x$ is unknown. I already have a numerical solution but for optimization purpose and generalization I would need to have a closed formula. It would be nice to have a solution based on well known and already well implemented functions such as Lambert  function, or generalized hyper-geometric . Any opinion or clue on the way to solve such equation would be very useful.

Comment: You could set $k_2=r\cdot k_1$, where $r$ is a rational number. You will get a radical equation in $e^x$ then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align} 
a\exp(k_1x) - b\exp(k_2x) + c &= 0
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

The expression \eqref{1}
is equivalent to

\begin{align}
p\,z^u-q\,z-1&=0
\tag{2}\label{2}
\\
\text{for }\quad
z&=\exp(k_1\,x)
,\\
u&=\frac{k_2}{k_1}
,\quad
p=\frac bc
,\quad
q=\frac ac
.
\end{align}

Unfortunately, it is known that
equation of the form \eqref{2}
does not have a closed-form
solution, not even in terms
of the Lambert W function,
unless $u$ happens to be
a small integer less than $5$
hence, the numerical root finding
is the only option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a new special function, the Lambert-Tsallis, proposed by R. V. Ramos at "Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications 525, 164-170" which can be used to solve. After a few manipulation you can find the folowing solution:

$$x=\frac{1}{k_1(\mu -1)} \cdot ln \left\{ \frac{-q}{p(\mu-1)}\cdot W_{\frac{\mu-2}{\mu-1}} \left[ \frac{p(\mu-1)}{(-q)^{\mu}}   \right]\right\}$$

To have a solution, there are some relations to be kept among the constants respect to the functions argumentos. It would be useful if you post some groups of constants.
For $a=16,b=20,c=-8, k_1=ln(3)$ and $k_2=ln(2)$ one should have $x=1$. The numerical solution for Lambert-Tsallis will be $0.307558538690483 + 0.000000000000041i$ which has generated the final $x=  0.999999999999753 - 0.000000000000329i$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ae^{k_1x}-be^{k_2x}+c=0\tag{1}$$
$x\to\ln(t)$:
$$at^{k_1}-bt^{k_2}+c=0\tag{2}$$

For $a,b,c,k_1,k_2,t\in\mathbb{N}$, equation (2) is a [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation).

For algebraic $a,b,c$ together with rational $k_1,k_2$, equation (2) is related to an algebraic equation and we can use the known solution formulas and methods for algebraic equations.

For real or complex $k_1,k_2\neq 0,1$, equation (2) is in a form similar to a trinomial equation. A closed-form solution can be obtained using confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $\ _1\Psi_1$ therefore.

see also: [How to isolate $x$ in $a^x + b^x = c$? (For use in medical statistics)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109555/how-to-isolate-x-in-ax-bx-c-for-use-in-medical-statistics/4496115#4496115)

[Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)

[Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)