# How do you get an expression for $x$ in terms of $c$ in the equation $\ln(x)=cx$?

Tags: logarithms, transcendental-equations

I am in the middle of solving this problem and I came across a sub problem that sorta has the format

$$\ln(x)=cx$$

I tried looking online on how to solve for $x$ if given $c$ but I couldn't find anything that I understood fully.  What I want to know is how to express $x$ in that equation in terms and $c$ and without logarithms in the final expression.

Comment: Raise both sides to the power of $e$:

$$x = (e^c)^x$$

Then you'll have to follow the steps outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3790499/597568) with $a=e^c$, $b=1$, and $c=0$ ($c$ as in the equation in the linked question, not your $c$).

The short version, though, is that you can't solve it without the rather complicated [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: @EeveeTrainer thank you..... I guess I will have to look into the lambert function then

Comment: You can manipulate the equation $x = e^{cx}$ to 

$$(-cx) e^{-cx} = -c$$

which has the form $we^w$ on the LHS and no $x$ on the RHS. Then assuming the RHS is in the range of $we^w$ and the domain of the $W$ function,

$$-cx = W(-c)$$