# Hello is anyone able to solve this $3^{x} - 2x = 25$. Im stuck and need help please

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve for $x$.

Im having trouble. I solved a similar problem $2^{x} + x = 37$, but ive been having trouble with this one. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Where do you want your solutions to lie?

Comment: You're not going to find a solution without the Lambert $W$ function. Luckily I wrote a more general question addressing that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790499/how-does-one-solve-for-x-in-the-equality-ax-bx-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one solve for $x$ in the equality $a^x = bx + c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790499/how-does-one-solve-for-x-in-the-equality-ax-bx-c)

Comment: Do you need to solve for intergal $x$ or real $x$ (in which case you will have to use Lambert W)

Comment: Can you tell us how you solved $2^x+x=37$ and where that method failed for this equation?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned elsewhere, you could use the Lambert W function after a lot of algebra. You can get an answer by figuring out what integers straddle the Real solution, then derive a new equation for an "offset" from the integer guess. Using Taylor series you can translate that equation into a linear equation solvable with simple algebra techniques.

$3^x-2x=25$

$f(x)=3^x-2x-25$

$f'(x)=\ln3 \cdot 3^x-2$

$f'(x)=0\implies x=\ln(\frac{2}{\ln 3})/\ln 3 \approx 0.54$

$f(0)=-24$ ,$f(1)=-24$,$f(2)=-20$

$f(3)=-4$,$f(4)=48$

So the answer is between $3$ and $4$.

---

$3^x=2x+25$

$x=3+\delta$

$3^{3+\delta}=2(3+\delta)+25$

$27\cdot 3^\delta=2\delta + 31$

$3\ln 3 + \delta \ln 3=\ln 31+\ln(1+2\delta/31)$

$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+...$

$\ln|1+x|=x-x^2/2+...$

$3\ln3+\delta \ln 3 = \ln 31 + 2\delta/31$

$\frac{3\ln3-\ln 31}{2/31-\ln 3}=\delta$

$3+\delta = \frac{6/31-\ln31}{2/31-\ln 3}\approx 3.13359525339$

If $c=3.13359525339$, then $3^c-2c-25\approx 0.0011$